# How to extract only the 1st table tag from a html page having various nested table tag

Tags: html, regex, c#-4.0

I have the following html page. I want to extract data only within the 1st table tag in C#. the html page code is:

```
<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100%>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align=right><b>11/09/2013&nbsp;at&nbsp;09:48</b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<center>
<table border="1" bordercolor="silver" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width=100>ETA</th>
<th width=100>Ship Name</th>
<th width=80>From port</th>
<th width=80>To berth</th>
<th width=130>Agent</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>11/09/2013 at 09:00&nbsp;</td>
<td>SONANGOL KALANDULA&nbsp;</td>
<td>Cabinda&nbsp;</td>
<td>Valero 6&nbsp;</td>
<td>Graypen&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

To be more specific I want to extract only the row having date `11/09/2013 at 09:48` the below mentioned code is under the first of  tag I am using regex

```
"<table[^>]*>([^<]*(?:(?!</table)<[^<]*)*)[</table>]*"
```

but with this I am getting whole of the page source that is I am getting the data between all the table tags but I want only text between first table tag.

Can anyone tell me regular expression with which I can only extract this particular portion from the whole html page?

Comment: Have you considered using an html parser?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of scenario where regexes are not the way to go for handling HTML input. If you have a limited, known set of HTML, regexes might be a quick solution. But it is precisely the nested tags with unknown depth that they can't handle. I would also advice looking at a HTML parser for this.

Answer (score 0):

When trying out your version here, it seems to work to me on the input you specified, though `[</table>]*` should really be just `</table>` (`[</table>]*` means any number of characters in the set: <,/,t,a,b,l,e,>)

This seems like it would bear simplification, though.  This should also work:

```
<table[^>]*>.*?</table>
```

All bets are off if you have nested tables, of course.